# In GIT, what is the difference between "git config user" and the actual credentials of GitHub account

Tags: git, github, credentials

I've already read what's on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60138385/difference-between-local-git-config-parameters-and-github-account), but still it's not clear for me. Basically, as far as I can tell, I can use as `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` whatever I want, regardless of the real GitHub account I'm using (of which asks me the credentials the first time I make `git push`).

Moreover, on the GitHub commit, it shows the `user.name` and not the username of the actual GitHub account. So the point is, what's the difference between them? What's the point of having `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just two separate things. The only reason they relate to each other is because **we** make an implicit relation between the GitHub account and the user who's email is in the commits (ACTUALLY this is not completely true, but more on that later. I'm trying to make a point).

Okay, more formally: Yes, your understanding is correct that you can set any `user.name` and `user.email`, regardless of the actual GitHub account. Why can that happen?

*Because* `git` as in your `.git` project **does not care** where you host your code. It can be on GitHub, on GitLab, or Bitbucket, self hosting, on the same machine in a different folder, wherever. All `git` cares about is the fact that for each commit, there is a person who created that commit, his/her name is known and his/her email is known. That is what a user is to git, that is what git uses a user for (In it's most basic form).

So why have a GitHub account? *Because* it's just another online platform, where you need to have an account on. It's no different than having a Facebook or Twitter account.

That's the reason we have an *implicit* connection between the two. Because any of your git projects don't care about GitHub or any other service, and GitHub won't really complain what email and name you use.

You and I and anyone actually can **fake** our git accounts and just create false commits and push them willy nilly to our own GitHub accounts. Yes you can do that. You can take my email and username, which I use for my commits and commit to **your** projects. Why to yours? Because you can authenticate **your** GitHub account. You **cannot** push to my projects unless I give you rights or you know my GitHub account!

Okay, last but not least, I lied to you a little bit in the beginning. I am constantly saying that we have an *implicit* connection between the two, but it's more than obvious that it's not exactly that. The better way to say it: GitHub has a hard relation with your `git.username and git.email`, while `git` on its own cares very little about such providers. We can see that GitHub has such a relation with your `git` account due to security constraints...

Here is part of the documentation from GitHub

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of the following conditions:
>   The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.

So technically YES, you can fake being other people, but you won't get anything from that.

**Edit** This is also a nice time to point out that `git` also supports *signing* commits/tags. A way for you to **prove** that **you** are the actual author of your commits and not some random hacker. Whether you should do it or not is a whole other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Github basically just hosts a git server. The github credentials are so that github knows you are authorized to actually push onto the git server, then `user.name` and `user.email` are so that the actual git server knows what to display your commits as.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but I don't understand why I'm able to use different usernames and emails than the one specified in the GitHub. Is that a feature I'm missing the point of?

Comment: Because GitHub and the git server are separate. The git server doesn't actually know about your github account details.

Comment: So basically is like I have a "git server" running locally on my pc which uses user.name and user.email, and then, the git server running on GitHub uses the credentials of the GitHub account, right?

Comment: Yes, it is like that.